# Script to inventory fileserver items older than 5 years

Tags: powershell, inventory, fileserver

I'm working on cleaning up fileservers and I need to move data from the source to a specific archiving destination. I will process this work with Robocopy.

For now I need to export an inventory of the fileservers to get an overview with the folders completed with items in there older than 5 years. Since I am not a hero in PowerShell I hope there is somebody who can give me a start with this script. The intention is that when I have an inventory I will move the folders with the items in there older than 5 years exactly in the same structure.

For now I have below but this is not working, maby you can complete me.

Thanks in advance!

```html
Get-ChildItem -Path "source" -Recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-date).AddYears(-5)}
```

Comment: The problem now is that when I export data all documents older than 5 years are sequentially displayed instead of staggered per folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move from `c:\dir1\path1` to `c:\dir2` with the same file structure do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "source" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-date).AddYears(-5)} | % { cp $_ ($_ -replace 'c:\dir1\path1', 'c:\dir2') }
```

Comment: The problem now is that when I export data all documents older than 5 years are sequentially displayed instead of staggered per folder.

Comment: That wont happen with above code - it keeps directory structure, just replaces first directory in hierarchy.